# Htmlunit selecting input running Dojo javascript package

Tags: javascript, dojo, selection, htmlunit, textinput

So I am trying to access a textbox in order to change the box from the default "Select Customer" to "PE".  My issue is the element is recognized by Htmlunit as a HtmlTextInput rather than HtmlSelection. I have learned that it runs dojo which complicates things a bit.

Here is the snippet of code I am trying to manipulate.

```
<form action="#" method="GET">
<span class="headlines">Customer:</span>
<select id="orgSelect"
name="orgSelect"
dojoType="dijit.form.FilteringSelect"
labelType="text"
    style="width: 150px;visibility:hidden"
autoComplete="true"

<option value="__select__" selected>Select Customer</option>
<option value="-1">**All Customers**</option>

<option value="2396-1986">PCLP</option>

<option value="3-1987">PE</option>

<option value="8262-1988">PEA</option>
```

My code is

```
List <HtmlForm> f= page.getForms();
HtmlTextInput ba = f.get(0).getInputByName("orgSelect");
ba.setValueAttribute("PE");
```

Here is what the Text version looks like.

Customer:
Select CustomerPE

?

Report Category:
Select Report Category_*select*_

Answer (score 0):

You can't set HtmlSelect directly.

You simply need to 'select' the good option within the select.

eg :

```
    HtmlSelect select = page.getHtmlElementById("myId");
for (HtmlOption o : select.getOptions()) {
    if (o.getValueAttribute().contains("myValue")) { 
        select.setSelectedAttribute(o, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks maxmax however I am still getting a exception. 

java.lang.ClassCastException: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTextInput cannot be cast to 
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSelect

Any other thoughts? 
Again thanks for everything.

Comment: HtmlSelect select = (HtmlSelect) page.getHtmlElementById("myId"); of course you need to provide the right id.

Comment: Its not that I cannot find the element, I am getting a class cast exception. It is expecting a HtmlText instead of HtmlSelect and it is saying I cannot cast it. This is the code I am using.
 HtmlSelect select = (HtmlSelect)page.getHtmlElementById("orgSelect");

If you look at my original post you can see that the id of the select form is correct. Any other suggestions? Thanks again.

Comment: I assume there's some dojo DOM changes done. Is the original post code from your web browser or by a page.getWebResponse().getContentAsString() ? if it's not by the getContentAsString() method, try it to check that you get same output. If it's it, that's really strange, can you share the url to this page ?